# How to Push Arrays in localStorage in a specific JSON Object format in REACT JS?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, local-storage

I have a REACT JS Client side where I want to save **Shopping Cart items** in localStorage by using **push** method.  I have an **AddtoCart** function which will Push the product details array of the product which is clicked, to localStorage JSON object **CartObj**.

But what I want is to have the entire CartObj of localStorage in a JSON Object format in which Products are grouped according to their **CompanyNames** (instead of just simple Strings).

When I Click "**AddtoCart**" button Im sending a single Product details in this format:

```js
{
"SparePartID":"45",
"Name":"Lights",
"Price":"2300",
"VendorID": "48",
"CompanyName": "Master Automotives",
"Qty": 1,
"TotalPrice": "4500"
}
```

And what I want is to **push** this above item in **CartObj** **JSON object** in localStorage (CartObj is currently empty). And whenever any item is clicked, its data is pushed to the same **CartObj**. But I want to get this below format of data in my localStroage **CartObj**  after few items are pushed in it. (**items grouped by CompanyNames**).

```js
{
    "records": {
        "Master Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "43",
                "Name": "Oil and Lubricants",
                "Price": "4500",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "4500"

            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "45",
                "Name": "Lights",
                "Price": "2300",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "2300"
            }
        ],
        "Repair Solutions": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "47",
                "Name": "Steering Wheel",
                "Price": "1500",
                "VendorID": "60",
                "CompanyName": "Repair Solutions",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "1500"
            }
        ],
        
         "FiveStar Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "51",
                "Name": "Brakes",
                "Price": "234",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "234"
            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "53",
                "Name": "Clutch",
                "Price": "999",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "999"
            },
              {
                "SparePartID": "55",
                "Name": "LED",
                "Price": "288",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "288"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**CAN I  DO IT** by push method in **localStroage** or is there any other way to save data in localStorage in this format. I want this format coz I need to handle order placement of these products **separately**.

here is my ADdToCart method in REACT:

```js
  AddToC(part){
    console.log("PartID to be added in cart: ", part); //this part shows details of a product in format I mentioned on very top.

    const alreadyInCart = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('cartObj'));
    alreadyInCart.push(part);


  }
```

**EDIT:**

```js
{this.state.spareParts.map((part, index) =>


<div>

  <h4 > {part.Name}  </h4>
  <h5> Rs. {part.Price}  </h5>


  <h5> {part.CompanyName} </h5>
<div>

  <button onClick={() => this.AddToCart(index, part.SparePartID)}
  Add to Cart
</button>

</div>


)}
```

Comment: Where you store that `records`, on state component ?

Comment: `const unsub = store.subscribe(() =>
  localStorage.setItem("languages", JSON.stringify(store.getState().languages))
);
`
A simple example, how to store using redux, maybe you are saving the incorrect Object. try to save the `records`.

Comment: @EdisonJunior I dont want to use redux. Is there any other way?

Comment: it was a simple ex, you can use what you want, Where you store your `records`, can you share your code ?

Comment: @EdisonJunior I dont have "records" existing anywhere. Im just supposing this records JSON Object when user adds multiple items in the cart, then thats how the data should look like. I first wanna store all items on localStorage then store them in a state component

Comment: you are using localStorage like a global state, its right ?

Comment: Yes right, im using localStorage as a global state

Comment: can you share your localStorage.setItem?

Comment: @EdisonJunior see my edit. thats how im sending each item details to AddtoCart function. and I have not written localStorage.setItem yet. Thats where I want help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use react Context for the Global variable, can once you store the value in the react Contect you can access that value from any component tree, its like global varibale and easy to understand than redux. so best practice is to use React Context,

For more info you can go through the link

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html